# PHP mail ends up as gmail junk

Tags: php, email

Been searching all over the net and tried many different solutions, also with phpmailer and other libraries.

My goal is to send a confirmation mail from my website, it works with hotmail and other services, but with gmail it ends up as junk.

Using the `mail()` function, and page is hosted on one.com and sending mail do exists.

The code:

```
$mime_boundary = 'Multipart_Boundary_x'.md5(time()).'x';

$headers = "";

$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";

$body    = "This is a multi-part message in mime format.\n\n";

# Add in plain text version
$body   .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
$body   .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"charset=us-ascii\"\n";
$body   .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
$body   .= "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";
$body   .= "\n\n";

# Add in HTML version
$body   .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
$body   .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n";
$body   .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
$body   .= $this->_message;
$body   .= "\n\n";

$body   .= "--{$mime_boundary}--\n"; #

$headers .= 'From: Sender <sender@example.com>'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: Sender <sender@example.com>'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Return-Path: Sender <sender@example.com>'."\r\n";

$headers .= 'Message-Id: <' . md5(uniqid(microtime())) . '@example.com>'."\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Sender-IP: ". $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] ."\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/'. phpversion() ."\r\n";

mail($this->_to, '=?UTF-8?B?'. base64_encode("Subject - ". $this->_subject) .'?=', $body, $headers, "-f sender@example.com");
```

Comment: Do you have an SPF record? Does it match your server? Have you tried DKIM?

Comment: @Slaks does GMail look for DKIM records too? I knew about SPF though.

Comment: @greut: I don't know, but it may help.

Comment: how can i look that up? as the page is hosted on one.com, and have no control over the server its hosted on

Comment: sender@example.com must be a well-known spammer then. Check the original message (top right drop-down) for some hints.

Comment: real sender is utskick@pengaboken.se

Comment: @trembon: You can check if you have an SPF record by going into terminal and typing `dig -t txt pengaboken.se` and seeing if there is a corresponding SPF entry in the TXT records.

Comment: terminal, hmm, sry, i'm on windows :P

Answer (score 2):

that simple, check if domain one.com is blacklisted:

http://www.mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3a195.47.247.192

Comment: If your domain is not blacklisted but still goes to junk mail folder, there are few reasons for that: 1, Similar message was sent more times. 2, Subject looks like spam (eg. Buy something) 3, suspect mime headers, etc

Comment: can post the mail body and subject to, though it is in swedish :)

Answer (score 1):

Check that your IP (or your server's IP) isn't blacklisted: http://www.dnsbl.info/dnsbl-database-check.php

Answer (score 0):

As I remember need to be without space in last parameter.

```
"-fsender@example.com"
```

instead of

```
"-f sender@example.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

This **[great post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html)** from @JeffAtwood gives a huge amount of information regarding the caveats one will encounter when sending email and what should be done in order to reduce the probability of ending in the junk/spam folder.

Comment: tried what is was able to, result from mail was:
SPF Check : neutral
Sender-ID Check : neutral
DomainKeys Check : neutral
DKIM Check : neutral

Comment: If you change the sender email address, the mail subject and its content (making it look like a personal email), does it still ends in the junk/spam folder?

Comment: Sender: utskick@pengaboken.se    Subject: Pengaboken.se - Välkommen   Body: Welcome text with a link to activate an account = mail ends up in junk went sent to gmail accounts, hotmail and other is fine

Comment: if you **change** those to different sender, subject and content (without a link) does it still fail?

Comment: changed, and did not work. Though now when changed, it ends up in junk on hotmail to